# don't want to set value of string static

Tags: android

I want to set the string value initially when application starts without making it static & further more i want to set the value of string variable by the user input. How can i set the values firstly & afterward get it by the user???

Kindly help me

Comment: You should also post some code snippet where you use the static variables that you don't want to be static. I bet your are using them in a static method.

Comment: miNde i posted the code where i used the static variables. Now please suggest

Comment: If your "pswd_auth" should not be changed during the execution of the program I recommend you to declare it "final". This way it couldn't be modified by mistake.

Comment: Now it gives an error that "The final field ETrackActivity.pswd_auth cannot be assigned"

Comment: Probably because your are trying to change its value somewhere else in your program. Is it something you want or not ?

Comment: Yes, but i firstly initialize value. then i get it from user.

Comment: Ok, I meant you can declare it final if it can be initialized when declaring it. If you have to initialize it later, so at the execution of the program, and not directly in code, then you should not declare it final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway it is a bad practice to have some static fields in your Activity. You can just initialize your property as usual.

```
private String pswd_auth= "13579";
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem goes beyond the code that you have shown. I think it would help you to understand what static means. Have a look at [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Basically, somewhere else in you're program you must be saying `ETrackActivity.pswd_auth`. When you set paswd_auth to static, it means that each instance of ETrackActivity doesn't have it's own value for paswd_auth, but instead there is one value that belongs to the entire definition of the class.

Static

```
MyCustomClass.myValue = 10
```

Non-static

```
MyCustomClass myInstance = new MyCustomClass();
myInstance.myValue = 5;
MyCustomClass anotherInstance = new MyCustomClass();
anotherInstance.myValue = 7;
```

Comment: @miNde now suggest whats Ur opinion

Comment: if(ETrackActivity.pswd_auth.equals(pswd_auth.getText().toString())) You are referring ETrackActivity.pswd_auth in a static way. If you dont want the field to be static, you have to change this. I would suggest reading the article I linked to and thinking about how you want to organize this.